# List of publicly available ethereum nodes (geth debug rpcapi)

Tags: remix

As a fun of Remix Debugger, it's necessary to connect to geth nodes with `debug` API turned on.
I'd like to know if there is list of such nodes.

Comment: Hi! Did you manage to find any? Also looking for this since full geth sync is going to take forever...